# Bootstrap Grid system - best practice - margins

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following layout. I can't use navbar, so instead I used the Grid system and gave it background.

[image: Grid sys]

How can I make this layout responsive? How can I leave spaces between the `div`s inside my `container` (e.g. searchbox)? Are there any helper classes in the Bootstrap framework that allow me to achieve this?

Comment: what kind of data do the first two columns hold ? Right now it looks more of a 3 + 2 + 7 grid structure

Comment: yes.. it might be anything.. this is just an example. It will be an item to filter the data of a search result displayed along with adding multiple filter criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add margin to the `<div>` tags inside a container or row, but Bootstrap was designed for responsive web apps. So unless you come up with a way of defining your margins not as literalls, but based upon the screen size, it won't be as reponsive as you might wish it to be. Also, please avoid altering the margin of something with the class `container`, `row` or `col`

My recommendation. On the `div` with `col-lg-7` or whatever the number might be, include another row, so that you can organize the layout in whatever way you need. If you want to leave a certain space betweeen elements, use 'col-lg-offset-x' according to your needs; with 'x' being the amount of spaces you want between elements. This will too sum up to 12.

Let me give you an example

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <!--Whatever you want to include here-->
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <!--Whatever you want to include here-->
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-7">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-4">
        <!--Whatever you want to include here-->
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-5">
        <!--Whatever you want to include here-->
      </div>
    </div>        
  </div>
</div>
```

You will need to add the `col-md-x`, `col-sm-x` and `col-xs-x` classes to fit your needs.
I hope it helps.